# Meaning of "concierge programs"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is the text I found this phrase in:

> #### Consider to Pay Special Attention to Top Management and Top Performers
>
> While certain parts of employee care should equally apply to all employees,
>   also consider special programs for those people you want to retain most, for
>   example, your top management and/or your top performers. **Concierge programs
>   are one option to enhance work-life balance for these target groups.**

Comment: Is it a sort of education or training? would you please provide more context? In general, the definition of the word is clear: 
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/concierge

Comment: Consider to Pay Special Attention to Top Management and
Top Performers
While certain parts of employee care should equally apply to all employees, also
consider special programs for those people you want to retain most, for example,
your top management and/or your top performers. Concierge programs are one option
to enhance work-life balance for these target groups.

Answer (score 1):

At higher end hotels, the **concierge** is the person who can help you with making restaurant reservations, flower deliveries, theater tickets, and generally making your life run smoother.

The author of your article is suggesting that a **concierge program** is a program or process put in place by a sponsoring organization to help and ease the lives of certain important employees to help their day-to-day lives run more smoothly.

> [Today, you can find **concierge programs** everywhere -- in hospitals, shopping malls, large corporations, apartment buildings, office buildings, airports, colleges and even churches.
>   The popularity of these concierge services stem from the fact that people are feeling overworked, overwhelmed, stressed out and short of time at home and in the workplace.](http://hotelexecutive.com/business_review/376/building-a-concierge-program-for-life)

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. Can we assign a synonym to the phrase "Concierge Program"?

Comment: Possibly "Lifestyle Support Program".

Comment: and what do you mean by that?

Comment: The concierge helps arrange things (tickets, reservations, purchases) and therefore helps "support" one's lifestyle.